# DATEDIFF based on ID in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to exclude rows from my query based on the following condition.

> 1. Calculate the time difference between EID of 33 and 49
> 2. If the total seconds is less than 35 exclude them from query

```
SELECT c1.* FROM CTE2 C2
INNER JOIN CTE C1
ON C2.ID = C1.ID
AND c1.EID IN (33,49)
ORDER BY C1.ID, C1.DateTime
```

My data may contain multiple rows for the same ID with duplicated `EID=33`, but it will always have one `EID=49`. So I'm interested in `last record` for ID minus `previous` row for the same ID. If it's less than `35` seconds exclude this `ID` from results.

I have tried using `Lag` function and adding an `AND` statement to the query above

```
AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, DateTime, LAG(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY id, datetime)) < 35
```

But I get the following error:

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

I did try a different approach:

```
;with cte AS 
(
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DateTime) AS RN 
   FROM @cte WHERE eid IN (33,49)
)
SELECT a.*, DATEDIFF(SECOND,a.datetime, b.DateTime) AS diff
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
ON a.id = b.id
AND a.RN = b.RN -1
AND DATEDIFF(second, a.DateTime, b.DateTime) < 35
```

But that still not returning me the correct data.

Here's a sample records.

[image]

Based on this records it should only return `ID=12345` and exclude `ID=54321` since the difference is only 12 seconds.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I'm not able to create a SQLFIDDLE. Here's a SCRIPT to create a TEMP table.

```
DECLARE @cte as table 
(
   ID Char (5),
   [DateTime]  DateTime,
   EID integer
)

INSERT INTO @cte
VALUES
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:14:57.000', 1 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:01.000', 2 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:12.000', 5 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:13.000', 12 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:13.000', 13 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:27.000', 16 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:27.000', 22 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:27.000', 23 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:39.000', 26 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:39.000', 32 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:42.000', 52 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:42.000', 33 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:15:52.000', 48 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:16:37.000', 33 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:17:13.000', 35 ), 
( N'12345', N'2016-03-15 13:17:13.000', 49 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:55:30.000', 1 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:55:30.000', 50 ),  
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:55:32.000', 2 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:56:30.000', 5 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:56:30.000', 12 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:56:30.000', 13 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:57:44.000', 16 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:57:44.000', 22 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:57:44.000', 23 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:57:56.000', 26 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:57:56.000', 32 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:57:59.000', 52 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:58:54.000', 33 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:59:06.000', 35 ), 
( N'54321', N'2016-03-24 20:59:06.000', 49 )
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle for us to work with. Thanks

Comment: I always do, and I tried, but the site is not responding at all.

Comment: I see. Just paste the `CREATE` and `INSERT` script as part of the question.

Comment: Added the script for a temp table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just using aggregation?  Assuming that the 33s are always before the 49 (which seems to be the case based on the sample data):

```
select id
from @cte
group by id
having datediff(second,
                max(case when eid = 33 then datetime end),
                max(case when eid = 49 then datetime end)
               ) < 35;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. The only thing in `datediff` the first parameter should be `second` not `seconds`.

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation and `IN`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        ID,
        MAX33 = MAX(CASE WHEN EID = 33 THEN DateTime END),
        MAX49 = MAX(CASE WHEN EID = 49 THEN DateTime END)
    FROM @cte
    WHERE EID IN(33, 49)
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT * 
FROM @cte
WHERE ID IN(
    SELECT ID
    FROM Cte
    WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MAX33, MAX49)) >= 35
)
```